# Why is file being corrupted during the PHP force download script process?

Tags: php

Overall structure of a page in my website:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="remote2.php">
<input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Enter URL with http://" />
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="File Name.jpg" />
<input type="text" name="path" placeholder="File Path" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<?php
set_time_limit (24 * 60 * 60);
if (!isset($_GET['submit'])) die();
$destination_folder = 'uploads/';
$url = $_GET['file'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$newfname = $destination_folder . basename($name);
$file = fopen ($url, "rb");
if ($file) {
$newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");
if ($newf)
while(!feof($file)) {
fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
  }
  }
if ($file) {
fclose($file);
}
if ($newf) {
fclose($newf);
}
header('Pragma: public'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
echo readfile(str_replace(" ","%20",$newfname)); 
exit;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess you can understand what the code is for! I will try to explain it briefly.

URL format is like:-

```
/remote2.php?file=https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0jUI.jpg&name=Rose.jpg&submit=Upload
```

It is a force download script! When someone clicks on the link given above, script runs two activities.

**When the user click on the link first time**, (as following first activity[1]), it stores the file from `https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0jUI.jpg` in `uploads/` path! And[2] it also forces file to download in the browser.

**When a user click on it second time**, it doesn't fetch the file from `https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0jUI.jpg` again, it directly forces file to be downloaded from `uploads/Rose.jpg` path to the browser.

I hope I was able to explain it clearly.

My problem is that the during this process, file is getting corrupted. There is no changes in the size of the file, just file is being corrupted. When I tried to open the downloaded image, I just got a message "Invalid Image". Also tried to use another file format like `mp3`, but it still stays on the same problem.

What's wrong with this code? How can I solve it?

Comment: You could just copy the file: http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: Ever heard of a file upload, using `<input type='file' multiple='multiple' />`? Use it with the `$_FILES` superglobal. Either that or use AJAX with the JavaScript `FileReader` Constructor.

Comment: @PHPglue Unfortunately, dunno anything about it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is corrupted, because you output your HTML **and** file content in same page. Also you should get warning that `headers already sent` when using `header('...')`.

Move your PHP logic to output file in separate file and make sure it prints out **only** file content.